# System.debug logs not displaying on apex page action method

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have an action method in a VisualForce page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Query__c"
    extensions="Builder"
    tabStyle="links__tab"
    title="Query Edit"
    action="{!giveMeHi}"
    id="Builder">
```

In the `Builder` extension I have the method:

```
public void giveMeHi(){
            System.debug('dragon army');
        }
```

I can't tell if that method is getting called since my system.debug calls are not appearing in the logs. I have used the Developer Console, I have downloaded the logs directly.

Comment: is your apex logging at INFO or higher? -- then the debug line won't appear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [@crop1645](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2602/crop1645) commented, if the Apex Code logging level is set to high on the general trace settings or on the Builder class the log message won't appear. By default System.debug will log at the Debug level.

In the Developer Console, check your Apex Code Log Levels are Debug or lower. Check Both the General Trace Settings for User and for any Class specific traces for Builder.

[image]

[image]

You could try using a higher logging level:

```
System.debug(LoggingLevel.Error, 'Rabbit Army');
```

Or really prove it is being called by making a failing assertion:

```
System.assert(false, 'Bean!');
```

Comment: Logging level error is the only level I use when I absolutely need to see a debug entry. The assertion trick is also incredibly handy.

Comment: And +1 for catching the Ender's game reference. :)

Comment: @JoshuaDance I always thought Bean was a more interesting character. :)